# Proof of Clifford's theorem for modules

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory, modules

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_theory#Proof_of_Clifford.27s_theorem

I've a very easy question that I just can't seem to find the answer to. I'm self-studying so I can't ask anyone else.

Basically, in the proof in wikipedia above, why is it we can assume that $U$, an $F[N]$-submodule of $V$ restricted to $N$, even exists? Can't modules $V$ (and $V$ restricted to $N$) exist without irreducible submodules like $U$?

many thanks

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Clifford algebras?

Comment: @AndreySokolov: nothing whatsoever, except that they are named after the same person.

Comment: @Alex B. Not even the same person as far as I can see. The tag for Clifford-algebras was inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The proof does not exclude the possibility that the restriction of $V$ to $N$ is irreducible. Then $U$ is necessarily equal to $V$. For example $V$ could be 1-dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

In the wikipedia article you have linked $V$ corresponds to the irreducible representation $\pi$ which is of finite dimension. Hence, there is always an irreducible subrepresentation of $V_N$. (If $V_N$ is not irreducible itself, then there is a proper subrepresentation, necessarily of smaller dimension, take the proper non-zero subrepresentation of smallest dimension, this is necessarily irreducible.)

There is also a version for infinite-dimensional $V$, see e.g. [Karpilovsky: Clifford theory for group representations, Theorem 2.2.2], but it will not hold in full generality as e.g. mentioned [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Clifford_theory).